# Organize import disturbs comments

Tags: java, eclipse, comments, code-formatting

I've commented code like below :

```
/*System.out.println("Parsed in main : " + parsed);
System.out.println("Parsed sum " + (parsed.getHour() + parsed.getMinute()));
System.out.println(isSessionSelected("10:00:00 am"));*/
```

However, after `organize import` it disturb the import and look like this :

```
/*
* System.out.println("Parsed in main : " + parsed);
* System.out.println("Parsed sum " + (parsed.getHour() + parsed.getMinute()));
* System.out.println(isSessionSelected("10:00:00 am"));
*/
```

This eats my time as every time I uncomment code I have to remove extra *.

How to not let eclipse do this?

Comment: I don't see this behavior with Eclipse Neon. I copied your code from the first section, and ran the "organize imports", but nothing changed for me. Do you have any settings at: Window => Preferences => Java => Code Style => Organize Imports?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to remove those extra *.
in eclipse go to

Window->Preferences->Java->Code Style->Formatter.

Create a new profile by clicking on new button.
after that a new dialog appears,

Select Comments tab
uncheck Enable block comment formatting.

[image]